# VBA Help Needed(Concatenation)

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, user-defined-functions

I have a workbook that has a nearly infinite number of products in one column and in each subsequent column is an attribute about that product(where it is located, the size, the qty on hand, etc).

I am trying to develop a code that essentially grabs a product and on one line, displays all of the warehouses where that product is located in a concatenated form.

I am having an issue with my code, however, and I cannot seem to solve it. For those who do better with visuals,

[image: Attached is a picture of the data base I created and the code is below]

From the pic, I am trying to take each product in the 'Product ID' column and and in the first empty cell in the next empty column I would like to display every warehouse that has that product separated by a comma. Furthermore, I am essentially doing a v-lookup against the 'Inventory' sheet(meaning as my array table) and the warehouse code is in column 4 of that 'Inventory' sheet.

My Code:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim INVLast As String
Dim p As String
Dim c As Range
Dim count As Integer
p = 12

INVLast = Sheets("Inventory").Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Search & Find").Range("F12:G20000").ClearContents
count = 0



For i = 2 To INVLast
    If Sheets("Inventory").Cells(i, 2) = Sheets("Search & Find").Range("B12") Then
    For Each c In Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp))
        Sheets("Search & Find").Cells(p, 6) = Sheets("Inventory").Cells(i, 4).Value & ", " & c
     Next c
        p = p + 1
        c = c + 1
        count = count + 1

    End If

Next i


MsgBox "The number of warehouses that sell this product is " & "" & count
```

Comment: "a nearly infinite number of products" - that is a lot of products. How close to infinity are we talking?

Comment: That was a hyperbole. It's about 400k lines in the 'Inventory' Sheet and I am comparing with about 100K lines in the 'OSMI' sheet.

Comment: That is quite a lot of data. A pivot table would get you quite a long way there. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 2013. And how so? @SJR

Comment: Why is `INVLast` a string variable (given that you assign a row number to it and then use it to construct the bounds of your `for` loop)? Maybe declare it as a `long`.

Comment: Also, I think cells in Excel are limited to ~32.8k characters. If you have 400k rows of data on `Inventory` sheet, you may encounter the limit (in the form of an error) even if only 10% of those 400k rows are matches/get concatenated.

Comment: What is your specific problem?  Seems you could use the `Range.Find` method to locate each instance, and then gather the results into a string, or array, or collection.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i'm not an experienced coder and my code isn't pulling the data(the warehouses that also house that product) for each row on the "Search & Find" spreadsheet that has a Product ID. It's also not counting the number of values in the Product ID column in the "Search & Find" sheet